# Error when iterating multiple plots through Axes Object in Python by using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,500)
y = np.sin(x**2)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
for current_axis in axes:
    current_axis.plot(x,y)
```

The result is:

```py
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

If I dont iterate but execute the below, it works

```py
axes[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axes[1, 1].plot(x, x**2)
```

***Why I am unable to iterate the same Axes Array object?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the Axes object is a ndarray with dimension 2x2, that means that each row is another array. The solution it's easy, only add `.flatten()` to the Axes object to make it unidimensional:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,500)
y=np.sin(x**2)
fig, axes=plt.subplots(2,2)
for current_axis in axes.flatten():
    current_axis.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your axes array is 2 dimensional. An array, of arrays, of plots. When you only use 1 for loop, you're only accessing the first dimension. You can use 2 for loops, or maybe

```
for current_axis in axes.flatten():
```

That is if the dimensions of your axes are not too big. Flatten gets kinda expensive later on.